# How to dismiss PopupViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So, I have a view controller in my main.storyboard, which acts as a popup to my view. I need to know how to dismiss it. (it takes up the whole screen) Thanks! (objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view controller presented modally can be dismissed by performing `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`.